# Composition of plane rotations around different axes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, rotations

Source:
Devide, Vladimir. Mathematical Problems and Expositions: 1) Tasks from Abstract Algebra
Prove that compositions of plane rotations around different axes don't form a group. (there is one plane rotated around different axes)

We haven't reached this point in our lectures and I'm rather intrigued by this. I know what properties a group has, but I don't know how a rotation composition of this kind behaves.

So far, I' ve seen how the composition of rotations around the same axis can be represented by matrices and how the association can be interpreted as making either one step at a time or more steps at the same time.

Can anybody give me, if possible, a short insight into this specific problem?

Comment: The rotation needs to be around a line. Rotations around different lines, when composed, don't always form rotations.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is hard not to understand it now when you answered. This should've been obvious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experiment. Suppose you rotate the $xy$-plane about the $x$-axis and then rotate the resulting plane about  the $z$-axis. Can you get to that configuration by a single plane rotation from the initial configuration?

Comment: No, I can't. Thank you for your answer.